# I got errors adding inertiajs with vuejs 3 to oneui-bootstrap-admin-dashboard-template

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I got this https://preview.themeforest.net/item/oneui-bootstrap-admin-dashboard-template-ui-framework-angularjs/full_screen_preview/11820082 and I thought to add with inertiajs with vuejs 3 to it.

I installed and run Laravel 8 Starter Kit, but I found that datatables with jquery are used in this app.
As I do not need them I tried to clear them all from my app and in resources/js/app.js I added lines :

```
require('./bootstrap');

console.log('resources/js/app.js::')

Following rules on installing inertiajs on server and client parts.
 
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mount(el)
    },
})
```

but after that I got errors in browser console :

```
laravel.app.js:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dataset')
    at exports.createInertiaApp (laravel.app.js:10)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (laravel.app.js:19213)
    at __webpack_require__ (laravel.app.js:42957)
    at laravel.app.js:43115
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (laravel.app.js:42994)
    at laravel.app.js:43122
    at laravel.app.js:43124
```

Any idea why I got this error and how can it be fixed?

**UPDATED 1:**
I inserted @inertia tag BEFORE , so the bottom of the resources/views/layouts/backend.blade.php has:

```
...

</div>
</div>
<!-- END Header Search -->

<!-- Header Loader -->
<!-- Please check out the Loaders page under Components category to see examples of showing/hiding it -->
<div id="page-header-loader" class="overlay-header bg-body-extra-light">
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="w-100 text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END Header Loader -->
</header>
<!-- END Header -->


<!-- Main Container -->
<main id="main-container">
    @yield('content')
</main>
<!-- END Main Container -->

<!-- Footer -->
<footer id="page-footer" class="bg-body-light">
    <div class="content py-3">
        <div class="row fs-sm">
            <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-2 py-1 text-center text-sm-end">
                Crafted with <i class="fa fa-heart text-danger"></i> by <a class="fw-semibold" href="https://1.envato.market/ydb" target="_blank">pixelcave</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-1 py-1 text-center text-sm-start">
                <a class="fw-semibold" href="https://1.envato.market/AVD6j" target="_blank">OneUI</a> &copy; <span data-toggle="year-copy"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<!-- END Footer -->
</div>
<!-- END Page Container -->

<!-- OneUI Core JS -->
<script src="{{ mix('js/oneui.app.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Laravel Scaffolding JS -->

{{--  <script src="{{ mix('/js/laravel.app.js') }}"></script>--}}

@yield('js_after')
@inertia

</body>

</html>
```

But I got error :

```
[2021-12-04 04:49:56] local.ERROR: Undefined variable $page (View: /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/resources/views/layouts/backend.blade.php) {"view":{"view":"/ProjectLaravelStarterKit/resources/views/layouts/backend.blade.php","data":{"errors":"<pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-559595542 data-indent-pad=\"  \"><span class=sf-dump-note>Illuminate\\Support\\ViewErrorBag</span> {<a class=sf-dump-ref>#333</a><samp data-depth=1 class=sf-dump-expanded>
    #<span class=sf-dump-protected title=\"Protected property\">bags</span>: []
</samp>}
</pre><script>Sfdump(\"sf-dump-559595542\", {\"maxDepth\":3,\"maxStringLength\":160})</script>
"}},"exception":"[object] (Facade\\Ignition\\Exceptions\\ViewException(code: 0): Undefined variable $page (View: /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/resources/views/layouts/backend.blade.php) at /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/resources/views/layouts/backend.blade.php:517)
[stacktrace]
#0 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/resources/views/layouts/backend.blade.php(517): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(107): require('...')
#2 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(108): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem::Illuminate\\Filesystem\\{closure}()
#3 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(58): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->getRequire()
#4 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(61): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
#5 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Views/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(37): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
#6 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(139): Facade\\Ignition\\Views\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
#7 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(122): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#8 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(91): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#9 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/resources/views/dashboard.blade.php(153): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#10 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(107): require('...')
#11 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(108): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem::Illuminate\\Filesystem\\{closure}()
#12 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(58): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->getRequire()
#13 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(61): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
#14 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Views/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(37): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
#15 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(139): Facade\\Ignition\\Views\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
#16 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(122): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#17 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(91): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#18 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(69): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#19 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(35): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent()
#20 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(794): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->__construct()
#21 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(763): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse()
#22 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(695): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse()
#23 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#24 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/src/Middleware.php(82): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#25 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Inertia\\Middleware->handle()
#26 /ProjectLaravelStarterKit/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read UPDATED 1

Comment: It looks like that error appeared after I added inertiajs/vuejs. In template description I read 
"Now based on Bootstrap 5, with no jQuery in core ", but a lot of jquery references in site layout(navigatio menu, 
sidebar, notifications popup items...). Not sure can it be fixed somehow? Or just change template without 
bootstrap/jquery ?